# How do you construct a django template variable dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do you dynamically construct a django template variable that is

{{ variable_name_number }}

that will have the number in variable_name_number in a range like 1 to 10? I started with the below but how do I add i in variable_name? Also range() will not work in the for loop, so is it possible to pass a context as the range?

```
{% for i in range(10) %}
     {{ variable_name}}  # should be {{ variable_name_i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a bunch of variables named `variable_name_i`, the best way is to pass a list in as `variable_name` with each of the elements.

Then, you can use something like this to access each member of the list.

```
{% for i in variable_name %}
     {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have to build variables on runtime, and python don't have arrays.

Comment: Python does have lists. `variable_name = []` then `variable_name.append("some object")`

Comment: variable_name = [] is not an array. but that is besides the question.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but why do you need an array? Won't a list work?

Comment: please check your answer you said use array.